# Sort a Map on key using TreeMap and sending TreeMap to JSON

Tags: json, jsp

I m fetching data from database and putting it into TreeMap and putting TreeMap object in JSONObject as i required json object returned to ajax call where i will be just showing the all data i fetched in TreeMap. I want all the data to e sorted alphabatically so i put that in TreeMap. Problem is that i am not getting data in sorted manner..This would be pattern for the data that i supposed to sort : "Mumbai-Navi Mumbai-Andheri Branch","Mumbai-Navi Mumbai-Bandra Branch"..etc
Help me out guys

Comment: Keys of a JSON object have no order. If you rely on order of keys, you're doing somthing wrong. If you want something ordered in a JSON structure, use an array.

Comment: so i will have to put TreeMap object into JSONArray and then it will be sorted right? or anything else i will have to do ?